# Android animation reduce stutter/choppy/lag

Tags: android, multithreading, caching, animation

So I've been having animation issues especially when two animations happen at once or right when an activity loads. I understand it's probably a resource problem and a lot of things are going on in the main thread causing the animations to stutter.

I've found a couple interesting suggestions:
1. Threads (ThreadPoolExecutor)
**Here:** [How do I make my animation smoother Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976039/how-do-i-make-my-animation-smoother-android)
2. setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)
**Here:** [How does Android's setDrawingCacheEnabled() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763532/how-does-androids-setdrawingcacheenabled-work)
3. ViewGroup: animationCache = true
**Here**: http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/02/android-graphics-animations-and-tips-tricks/

However I haven't been able to find any sort of examples to implement these things. Any ideas?

Comment: AsyncTasks are also an easy way to implement background threads.
If you do a lot of calculations in the main thread, you definitely need to implement either thread or asynctasks, the main thread is here for the UI, not the heavy lifting.

Comment: Yea I know, I'm more looking for examples on animations being used with Threads/AsyncTasks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've reduced the amount of stutter on my animations by following these rules listed in order of importance when reducing stutter:

1. Don't initiate animations in `onCreate`, `onStart` or `onResume`.
2. Initiate animations on user events such as `onClick` and disable touch events until animation is complete.
3. Don't initiate more than 2 animations simultaneously.

Comment: how can we " hault user interaction until animation is complete.??"

Comment: when you start the animation, set a variable like animStart = 1, and check that variable when you are going to handle button presses etc. So for example if you're moving a layer, you don't want users pressing the button while the layer is re-positioning. So set the variable, and unset it when the animation finishes

Comment: What would be the best way to achieve it? And what if I needed to animate while the activity is loading?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "the best way to achieve it," it's really however you wanna do it. As for the 2nd part. IMO you shouldn't animate WHILE an activity is loading. Instead, trigger an animation after the activity is loading and have the layout initially set to some picture or icon that lets the user know "stuff is going on". Example: initially the activity loads with a spinner (a busy icon) once the activity loads trigger a function that animates whatever you want and covers/removes the "busy icon"

Comment: @Rawr how do i know a activity complete loading? Are there any listeners?

Comment: @HaiHack This question/answer was from a decent time ago so I'm going off my memory here. I believe I got the best performance from loading a static placeholder and triggering some thread in the background to handle the animation `onResume`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using animation you should follow the android [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/animate); in fact in some cases, you might need to postpone your fragment transition for a short period of time. For example in my case I need to postpone my animation until my viewmodel return some data:

Use `postponeEnterTransition()` in the entering fragment `onViewCreated()` method:

```
public class A extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        postponeEnterTransition();
    }
}
```

Once the data are ready to start the transition, call `startPostponedEnterTransition()`

```
public class A extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        postponeEnterTransition();

        final ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        // Wait for the data to load
        viewModel.getData()
            .observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<String> list) {
                    // Set the data on the RecyclerView adapter
                    adapter.setData(list);
                    // Start the transition once all views have been
                    // measured and laid out
                    parentView.getViewTreeObserver()
                        .addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                            parentView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                .removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                            startPostponedEnterTransition();
                            return true;
                        });
                }
        });
    }
}
```